# Android Actionbar PopupMenu with Custom Item Layouts

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I am working on an Android application where I have to design a menu which will populate from the action bar, like this:
[image]

I have tried my best but was not able to produce it using the Android controls.

The solutions I have tried are:

1. With Actionbar, add a menu item with a group with selectable="all", that produces the layout I need but when I click a checkbox for selecting it, the whole menu hides and selection is not done, moreover the menu icon in actionbar does not have the bottom right white arrow.
2. Tried creating a custom ActionProvider and added the menu items using class's OnPrepareSubMenu method but had the same issue.

I just need a push in the right direction and I can do the rest, suggestions are more than welcome.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [popupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). 
In that you can make any custom layout and set it as content of your popupwindow and also you can specify an ANCHOR in your case it would be 
R.id.your_menu_item 
set a listener and listen the changes.